# Get random element from tuple ListBuffer

Tags: scala, random

I have this list:

```
val list =  ListBuffer[(String, String)]
```

Is it possible to get random `element` from my list base on condition from the second `element` ?

Comment: What do you mean by *"based on condition in the second element"*. Second element inside the `ListBuffer`? What is this condition you speak of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean - get a random tuple from those that pass a certain predicate - you can `filter` by this predicate and then choose a random element from the result:

```
scala> import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer
scala> import scala.util.Random

// some data
scala> val list = ListBuffer[(String, String)](("ab", "c"), ("de", "f"), ("gh", "c")) 
list: scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[(String, String)] = ListBuffer((ab,c), (de,f), (gh,c))

// some predicate on String:
scala> val f: String => Boolean = s => s == "c"
f: String => Boolean = <function1>

// this is not the most efficient way, for small lists it would do:
scala> Random.shuffle(list.filter(t => f(t._2))).head
res7: (String, String) = (ab,c)

// OR, if you're concerned about performance you can:
scala> val filtered = list.filter(t => f(t._2))
filtered: scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[(String, String)] = ListBuffer((ab,c), (gh,c))

scala> filtered(Random.nextInt(filtered.length))
res8: (String, String) = (ab,c)
```